# EXC_BAD_BREAKPOINT_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, breakpoints

Hi I Keep getting this error ***EXC_BAD_BREAKPOINT_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)*** and I can't seem to resolve it, the problem is at the end of the code where it says customcell.itemdetails.text = object["description"] as String! Thanks

```js
import UIKit

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
 
 // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
 override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
  super.init(style: style, className: className)
 }
 
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  
  // Configure the PFQueryTableView
  self.parseClassName = "Photo"
  self.textKey = "updatedAt"
  self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
  self.paginationEnabled = false
 }
 
 // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
  var query = PFQuery(className: "Photo")
  query.orderByAscending("updatedAt")
  return query
 }
 
 //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {
  
  var customcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell!
  if customcell == nil {
   customcell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
  }
  
  // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        
        customcell.itemdetails.text = object["description"] as String! 
        customcell.user.text = object["User"] as String!
        customcell.price.text = object["Price"] as String!
        
        var thumbnail = object["Image"] as PFFile
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        customcell.productimage.image = initialThumbnail
        customcell.productimage.file = thumbnail
        customcell.productimage.loadInBackground()
        
    
        
        
  return customcell
 }
    
}
```

and this is the code from the custom cell

```js
import UIKit

class CustomCell:  PFTableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var user: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productimage: PFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemdetails: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    
    

}
```

Comment: Try printing the content of `object` just before the problem line and pasting it into your question.  It's possible that the structure isn't what you expect.

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks do you know how to fix this

Comment: I don't know.  Show the information I asked about and I'll try.

Comment: @PhillipMills i have put the info you need up

Comment: Where?  (I asked about the content of `object`.)

Comment: @PhillipMills sorry I'm new to coding, what are these i assumed they were the code in the custom cell

Comment: You said the problem happened when you tried to use `object["description"]` so I'm suspicious about what's really inside the thing called `object`.  The best way I can think of to find out is to print it, then you can copy the result from Xcode's debug console.

Comment: sorry I'm really confused how do i find whats in the object

Comment: @PhillipMills how do i do this

Comment: @PhillipMills I have put the project up online at http://we.tl/U5kDsaFEbg is it possible for you to download it and try and get to the bottom of this error thank you